# Making sense of a proof in Linear Algebra Done Right: Operators on complex vector spaces have an eigenvlaue

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

I don't understand the last string of equalities in the proof below.

For the first equality, how do we know that we can we just pull out the v?

For the second equality, each summand is a function, how is it sensical to apply the fundamental of theorem of algebra to produce a bunch of functions composed together? As in, how do we know that, under the fundamental theorem of algebra, addition of linear operators can be applied to produce a composed function in the same way addition of polynomial terms can become a string of 1 degree terms multiplied together?

[image]

Comment: show that
$\phi : \mathbb{C}[X] \to \mathcal{L}(V)$, defined by $\phi(X^k)=T^k$, for all $k$, is a morphism.

Comment: I appreciate the attempt, but this does not help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The sum of two linear maps $T,U$ is defined by $(T+U)v = Tv+Uv.$ This definition is applied.
2. So the question is, if $$a_0 + a_1z + \ldots + a_nz^n = c(z-\lambda_1)\cdots(z-\lambda_n),$$
   why does the corresponding equality also hold if we fill in $z^k = T^k.$
   This follows from a rather general fact, that when $p(z)$ and $q(z)$ and $r(z)$ are polynomials with $r(z) = p(z)q(z)$ then if we substitute $z^k \to T^k$ the equality $$
   r(T) = p(T)q(T)$$ holds. Applying this $n-1$ times solves your problem: \begin{align*}a_0I + a_1T + \ldots + a_nT^n =& c(T-\lambda_1) \cdot \left[(T-\lambda_2)\cdots(T-\lambda_n) \right] \\ =&  c(T-\lambda_1)(T-\lambda_2) \cdot \left[(T-\lambda_3)\cdots(T-\lambda_n) \right] \\=& \ldots \\=& c(T-\lambda_1)(T-\lambda_2) \ldots (T-\lambda_n). \end{align*}

Also, here is a different proof you might like:
$T$ has an eigenvalue if and only if its corresponding matrix $A$ in some basis has an eigenvalue. The matrix $A$ has an eigenvalue if and only if $A - \lambda I$ is singular for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. This is so if and only if $\det(A - \lambda I) = 0 $ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}.$ This is true by the fundamental theorem of algebra, since $\det(A - \lambda I)$ is a polynomial in $\lambda.$

Comment: r(T)=p(T)q(T) --- is this not viewed as function composition? so it isnt the same as applying q(t) to v getting the result and then applying that result as the input to p(T)?

Comment: As in the only way to evaluate p(T)q(T) is multiply it out form R(T)

Comment: Yes, multiplication of two polynomials of transformations is defined as composition.  So for example, since $(z-1)(z+1) = z^2-1,$ the composition $(T-I)(T+I)=T^2-I$. (Try to show this by applying the left hand side to a vector $v$!)